# Showing Loading indicator while loading content in the inframe

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery, html

Code for Showing Loading indicator while loading content in the inframe
1)When a postback/submit take place in the form inside iframe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can bind to the `ajaxStart` and `ajaxStop` [global (ajax) events](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax_Events) as follows:

```
$("#loading").bind("ajaxStart", function(){
    $(this).fadeIn("slow");
}).bind("ajaxStop", function(){
    $(this).fadeOut("slow");
});
```

assuming `loading` is the ID of your loading indicator div/span.

If you want a prettier solution, take a look at the awesome [blockUI](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/) plugin. The equivalent of the above using blockUI:

```
$().ajaxStart($.blockUI)
   .ajaxStop($.unblockUI);
```